# Compare between 3 values and print final result

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, control-flow, nested-if

I have 3 variables that are inside a quiz and at the end of the quiz, 1 of those variables is going to be higher than the other ones, but it could also be that 1 of those variable has the exact value as another variable, or even that the 3 variables have exactly the same value. What function could i run to read those three variables and print the answer? (The problem im having is that it sometimes reads two variables that have the same value and prints that as the answer, while one variable is higher than those other two)

Im putting here the code im trying to do it with but it's not working with it

```
var VFinal = 9
var AFinal = 5
var KFinal = 5

var resultText = ""

     func finalResultText() {

        if VFinal > KFinal && VFinal > AFinal {
            resultText = "Visual, Auditive and Kinesthetic"
        } else if KFinal > VFinal && KFinal > AFinal {
            resultText = "Visual and Auditive"
        } else if AFinal > VFinal && AFinal > KFinal {
            resultText = "Visual and Kinesthetic"
        } else if KFinal == AFinal {
            resultText = "Auditive and Kinesthetic"
        } else if AFinal == VFinal {
            resultText = "Kinesthetic"
        } else if VFinal == KFinal {
            resultText = "Auditive"
        } else if AFinal == VFinal && AFinal == KFinal {
            resultText = "Visual"
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `AFinal == VFinal && AFinal == KFinal` ? Instead of the [bitwise `&`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID31)

Comment: Yes, but im still having the same problem

Comment: Move > condition before checking equally (==)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I just tried to do it, and for var "AFinal" i got 6, and for the other 2 i got 3 and 3 as the value, but the final answer printed me "Visual and Kinesthetic", when it should've been "Auditive", because it's the higher value. I put the updated function in the original code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This operation (KFinal > VFinal & AFinal) is wrong. It should be KFinal > VFinal && KFinal > AFinal
2. Moved the last three operations to the top

```
var VFinal = 5
var AFinal = 5
var KFinal = 5

    func finalResultText() {

        if KFinal > VFinal && KFinal > AFinal {
            print("Kinesthetic")
        } else if AFinal > VFinal && AFinal > KFinal {
            print("Auditive")
        } else if VFinal > KFinal && VFinal > AFinal {
            print("Visual")
        } else if AFinal == VFinal && AFinal == KFinal {
            print("Visual, Auditive and Kinesthetic")
        } else if AFinal == VFinal {
            print("Visual and Auditive")
        } else if VFinal == KFinal {
            print("Visual and Kinesthetic")
        } else if KFinal == AFinal {
            print("Auditive and Kinesthetic")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried the same code with that fix, but it still is giving me wrong answers.  I just tried to do it, and for var "AFinal" i got 6, and for the other 2 i got 3 and 3 as the value, but the final answer printed me "Visual and Kinesthetic", when it should've been "Auditive", because it's the higher value. I put the updated function in the original code below

Comment: Im getting this this (https://imgur.com/a/4hdrOnm) as an answer, when i should be getting "you are Auditive"

Comment: You can see in the print function in the image below why the text label answer is wrong

Comment: I tested my solution (var VFinal = 3, AFinal = 6, KFinal = 3). I am getting Auditive now. Please try my solution above, It's working correct (https://imgur.com/a/hQU6kDX)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I copy pasted your function and it worked!!! I was in this problem for days.